# How do I locate an element on a web page whose display text is dynamic

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver

How do I locate an element whose content is dynamic. The elements is a cell in a table which gets its value dynamically. Please refer to the below sample code:

```html
<tr class="oddrow " style="visibility: visible;">
   <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" onclick="WebForm.markRowForSelection(event)" id="check_ProcessDefinitionTable" xformstype="checkbox" selectnotifier="true" databoundelement="true" style="visibility: visible;"></td>
   <td>
      <div class="fieldsbox" id="xfe2" style="visibility: visible;"><input readonly="" isoutputcontrol="true" xformstype="output" id="clmFolder" xql="tns:Folder" databoundelement="true" __parent="ProcessDefinitionTable" class="input output left_align" absolutexpath="tns:Folder" datatype="string" validate="true" doebivalidate="false" title="Value for Folder." style="" ref="tns:Folder" xmlns:wcpforms="http://xyz.xyz.com/wcp/xforms" _intable="true" maxlength="999999999"></div>
   </td>
   <td>
      <div class="fieldsbox" id="xfe4" style="visibility: visible;"><input readonly="" isoutputcontrol="true" xformstype="output" id="clmShortname" xql="tns:ShortName" databoundelement="true" __parent="ProcessDefinitionTable" class="input output left_align" absolutexpath="tns:ShortName" datatype="string" validate="true" doebivalidate="false" title="Value for Name." style="" ref="tns:ShortName" xmlns:wcpforms="http://xyz.xyz.com/wcp/xforms" _intable="true" maxlength="999999999"></div>
   </td>
   <td>
      <div class="fieldsbox" id="xfe6" style="visibility: visible;"><input readonly="" isoutputcontrol="true" xformstype="output" id="clmDescription" xql="tns:Description" databoundelement="true" __parent="ProcessDefinitionTable" class="input output left_align" absolutexpath="tns:Description" datatype="string" validate="true" doebivalidate="false" title="Value for Description." style="" ref="tns:Description" xmlns:wcpforms="http://xyz.xyz.com/wcp/xforms" _intable="true" maxlength="999999999"></div>
   </td>
   <td>
      <div class="fieldsbox" id="xfe8" style="visibility: visible;"><input readonly="" isoutputcontrol="true" xformstype="output" id="clmModelspace" xql="tns:ModelSpace" databoundelement="true" __parent="ProcessDefinitionTable" class="input output left_align" absolutexpath="tns:ModelSpace" validate="true" datatype="string" doebivalidate="false" displayformat="text" title="Value for Published To." style="" ref="tns:ModelSpace" _intable="true" maxlength="999999999"></div>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr class="evenrow highlight" style="visibility: visible;">
   <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" onclick="WebForm.markRowForSelection(event)" id="check_ProcessDefinitionTable" xformstype="checkbox" selectnotifier="true" databoundelement="true" style="visibility: visible;"></td>
   <td>
      <div class="fieldsbox" id="xfe2" style="visibility: visible;"><input readonly="" isoutputcontrol="true" xformstype="output" id="clmFolder" xql="tns:Folder" databoundelement="true" __parent="ProcessDefinitionTable" class="input output left_align" absolutexpath="tns:Folder" datatype="string" validate="true" doebivalidate="false" title="Value for Folder." style="" ref="tns:Folder" xmlns:wcpforms="http://xyz.xyz.com/wcp/xforms" _intable="true" maxlength="999999999"></div>
   </td>
   <td>
      <div class="fieldsbox" id="xfe4" style="visibility: visible;"><input readonly="" isoutputcontrol="true" xformstype="output" id="clmShortname" xql="tns:ShortName" databoundelement="true" __parent="ProcessDefinitionTable" class="input output left_align" absolutexpath="tns:ShortName" datatype="string" validate="true" doebivalidate="false" title="Value for Name." style="" ref="tns:ShortName" xmlns:wcpforms="http://xyz.xyz.com/wcp/xforms" _intable="true" maxlength="999999999"></div>
   </td>
   <td>
      <div class="fieldsbox" id="xfe6" style="visibility: visible;"><input readonly="" isoutputcontrol="true" xformstype="output" id="clmDescription" xql="tns:Description" databoundelement="true" __parent="ProcessDefinitionTable" class="input output left_align" absolutexpath="tns:Description" datatype="string" validate="true" doebivalidate="false" title="Value for Description." style="" ref="tns:Description" xmlns:wcpforms="http://xyz.xyz.com/wcp/xforms" _intable="true" maxlength="999999999"></div>
   </td>
   <td>
      <div class="fieldsbox" id="xfe8" style="visibility: visible;"><input readonly="" isoutputcontrol="true" xformstype="output" id="clmModelspace" xql="tns:ModelSpace" databoundelement="true" __parent="ProcessDefinitionTable" class="input output left_align" absolutexpath="tns:ModelSpace" validate="true" datatype="string" doebivalidate="false" displayformat="text" title="Value for Published To." style="" ref="tns:ModelSpace" _intable="true" maxlength="999999999"></div>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Above `<td>` is one among three `<td>`s in a `<tr>`. The other `<tr>`s have `<td>`s with the same ids. In other words, The three cells in a row will have three ids. But the other rows have cells with the same three IDs.

How do I locate any one of the `<div>` or `<input>`

[image: Dynamic display contents]

Below is the snapshot for the above HTML code, I want to locate the listImport cell.

Comment: `id` is a unique attribute. If you are repeating the same `id` for different elements, consider changing your design.

Comment: It is a legacy web app that is being used by my company. I am just trying to automate our daily process.

Comment: Are there other attributes on the `input` that are unique?

Comment: @JustinPearce. Thank you for your quick response. I have edited my question to help you understand better.

Comment: Can you please add the selector that you have used to find the **ListImport**. Not able to find that column by using the given html.

Comment: Hi Justin, I can't find any unique attribute. Only the text that they display are unique. But they fetch this text from a Database or from the JavaScript. If you see the xql properties in the input tags, there is 'tns:ShortName' this should be from an xslt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to locate anyone `div` or `input`, you can use the below selector and you can modify according to your requirement,

```
WebElement target = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='fieldsbox']//input[@id='clmFolder']"));
```

You can change the `id` value to get the desired value from the table. Include trying `tr` or `td` before the selector in order to get the desired row. An example is shown below(just for reference, it may not be correct),

```
WebElement target = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[1]//td[1]//div[@class='fieldsbox']//input[@id='clmFolder']"));

tr[1] --> First row
td[1] --> First column
```

Comment: Hi @kripindas. Thank you for taking your time and helping me out. The above solution that you have provided will be absolutely perfect if the positions of the <tr> do not change. Here whenever a new <tr> is added, the positions change. And also, the text that they display is fetched from I don't know where (May be dynamically from the JavaScript or from a Database) and displayed. Ref: in the snapshot I have provided, one of the <tr> displays listImport for a <td> with the id shortName.

Comment: @GauravThantry   If it is dynamic then it is better to take the count of the `tr` and write a loop. Inside that loop put you desired text and check for that until it is found. So that you can go through all the `tr` and `td`.Please let me know if you can take the count of the `tr`.

Comment: Hi Kripindas. Your suggestion would work if the displayed text are hardcoded. But here, it fetches the text from a different source and not from the page source.

Answer (score 0):

Given the HTML structure, you may be able to locate the field in question with the following:

```
WebElement target = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value='ListImport']"));
```

This is using the CSS attribute selector for the `input` to locate it by one with a value set to `ListImport`. If that fails, you may have to do something like:

```
List<WebElement> inputs = driver.findElements(By.tagName('input'));
```

And then loop through each of the elements, evaluating the value of the field to find the one you are looking for. it is not very straightforward to target elements when there is little unique to identify them on the page.

Comment: Hi Justin. Thank you for trying to help me out. i really appreciate it.
The above code is not working because the contents are not being displayed from DOM. They are being fetched and then displayed. I tried to print the displayed text: 
List<WebElement> services = driver.findElements(By.tagName("input"));
      for(WebElement service : services )
      {
      String serviceName = service.getText();
      System.out.println(serviceName);
      }